# Allow access to anonymous feedback stats without 10k rep

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, privileges, 10k-tools, post-feedback

Right now you need the [Access To Moderator Tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege (awarded at 10k on a regular site, 2k on public beta, 1k on private beta) to access [anonymous feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback/) on that site. I don't see why that is, and I often want to view this info on sites where I don't have the privilege. So I have to use SEDE queries like [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/67918/top-100-posts-with-the-best-anonymous-low-rep-feedback) and [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/67919/top-100-posts-with-the-worst-anonymous-low-rep-feedback) to find this information.

**Please allow access to this information at a lower reputation.** I wouldn't even be averse to having that privilege at 100 rep, so you would get it with your association bonus.

Comment: You have access to this via SEDE; where's the problem?

Comment: @Shog9 It's a lot messier there (much slower and harder to find information), and further, there aren't any good reasons I can think of why users shouldn't be allowed to use the pages at a lower reputation. It's better.

Comment: Worth to mention it's broken on Stack Overflow (most likely too much data) so relevant only for the other sites.

Comment: I'd like to see this implemented. It's educational to users on many levels, which is crucial to maintaining the quality of SE. As for queries, many of us have neither the technical ability, nor the hardware platform, to perform them, so in my opinion enabling access would be best.

Comment: I don't see why you guys want to see anonymous feedback? I'm not saying there's no reason, I just lack enough experience to know why it would be useful. I look at 10k tools several times per day on a site where I'm extremely active, and rarely looked at the anonymous feedback.